# equivalent trace-conditions on $C^*$-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, trace

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra and $\tau:A\to\mathbb{C}$ linear. Claim: the following conditions are equivalent:

1. $\tau(ab)=\tau(ba)$ for all $a,b\in A$
2. $\tau(x^*x)=\tau(xx^*)$ for all $x\in A$
3. $\tau(uau^*)=\tau(a)$ for all positive $a\in A$ und for all unitaries $u$ in the unitization $A^1$ of $A$.

The direction 1=>2 is trivial. But I'm stuck to prove 2=> 3 and 3=>1.

One idea for the direction $3\Rightarrow 1$ is: If it's possible to prove that $\tau(ux)=\tau( xu)$ for all unitaries $u\in A^1$ and for all $x\in A$, I can conclude that $\tau(ax)=\tau(xa)$ for all $a\in A^1$ and for all $x\in A$ (because $a\in A^1$ can be written as a linear combination of unitaries), so I can conclude 1. But all my tries to prove $\tau(ux)=\tau( xu)$ for all unitaries $u\in A^1$ and for all $x\in A$ were pointless, can you help me?

I also have no idea how to do $2\Rightarrow 3$ . I would appreciate hints.

Best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for $2\implies 3$: you have, since $a\geq0$,
$$
\tau(uau^*)=\tau(ua^{1/2}a^{1/2}u^*)=\tau((a^{1/2}u^*)^*a^{1/2}u^*)
=\tau(a^{1/2}u^*(a^{1/2}u^*)^*)=\tau(a^{1/2}u^*ua^{1/2})=\tau(a^{1/2}a^{1/2})
=\tau(a)
$$

For $3\implies 1$: since the condition holds for positive $a$ and every operator is a linear combination of positives, the equality holds for arbitrary $a$: $$\tau(uau^*)=\tau(a).$$
In particular it holds for $au$, and we obtain $$\tau(ua)=\tau(au)$$ for $a\in A$ and $u\in A$ a unitary. Now, since $b$ can be written as a linear combination of unitaries, $\tau(ab)=\tau(ab)$.